# Angular 7 AmCharts PDF font

Tags: angular, amcharts

I'm using Angular 7 and AmCharts and I'm exporting a PDF (using the included pdfmake library), but I can't change the default font of the generated PDF. I alread created the `vfs_fonts.js` with the fonts I need and including it in my `angular.json` in the `scripts` section. In the component where I generate the report I do the following:

```
let pdfMake = res[0];

pdfMake.fonts = {
    "Open Sans": {
        "normal": 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
        "bold": 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
        "italics": 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
        "bolditalics": 'OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'
    }
}

let doc = {
    header: this.drawHeader(),
    footer: this.drawFooter(),
    pageSize: "A4",
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    pageMargins: [40, 80, 40, 60],
    content: [],
    defaultStyle: {
        font: "Open Sans"
    }
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Font 'Open Sans' in style 'normal' is not defined in the font section of the document definition.
Error: Font 'Open Sans' in style 'normal' is not defined in the font section of the document definition
```

How can i solve? Thank you

Comment: Try https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/864#issuecomment-298341323

Comment: I am going on a hunch here. Can you try removing the double quotes from "Open Sans", "normal", "bold", "italics", and "bolditalics"? In case of an error also try removing the space between Open and Sans, make it OpenSans. BTW, the issue has already been reported w/o a solution: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1169#issue-270877961

Comment: Same problem even after removing quotes

Comment: Please place the *vfs_fonts.js* file contents.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem to change the fonts of the pdf make library . I solved the problem using the following steps .

Initially , download the **.ttf** file of the fonts you required.

**Step 1)** 
 Go to the following path -> `node_modules -> pdfmake`

**Step 2)** 
In the directory of *pdfmake* , create the folder named *examples*. Go to *examples* folder and inside it , create a folder name *fonts*.

**Step 3)**
Now paste your downloaded **.ttf** files  inside the fonts folder . (path_to_paste_ttf_File : node_modules/pdfmake/examples/fonts)

Once you paste the files inside that folder. Continue to **step 4**

**Step 4)**
 Go to the path to fonts folder as mentioned in the terminal Look below  image terminal path for reference .
[image]

**Step 5)**
Once you complete the **step4** , rum `gulb buildFonts` . Your output will be like as below image. 
[image]

Once you build your fonts successfully. 

Go to your .ts file of your component where you are generating the pdf.

Inside **.ts** file

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;


async generatePdf(value){
        pdfMake.fonts = {
            Roboto: {
                normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
            }
        };
        const documentDefinition = await this.getDocumentDefinition();
        pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).open();
    }
    getDocumentDefinition(){
        return {
            content: (...),
              defaultStyle: {
                    font: 'yourFontName' //in this case it's roboto.
            }
        }               
    }
```

This solved My issue and let me know if you face any difficulties . 

For more reference , Follow the [official document](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/)

Comment: Again, I'm not using the standalone pdfmake library, I'm using the pdfmake library that is INSIDE AMCharts library, so I cannot do this

Comment: but after all you are concern with pdfmake library fonts . so why don't you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Pdfmake documentation on how to use custom fonts on client-side [here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/).

---

The **vfs_fonts.js** file format is something like:

```
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
  "Roboto-Italic.ttf": "AAEAAAASAQAABAAgR0RFRtRX1"
}
```

Therefore, you should define it like the following:

```
window.pdfMake.vfs["OpenSans-Regular.ttf"] = "BASE 64 HERE";
window.pdfMake.vfs["OpenSans-Bold.ttf"] = "BASE 64 HERE";
window.pdfMake.vfs["OpenSans-Italic.ttf"] = "BASE 64 HERE";
window.pdfMake.vfs["OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf"] = "BASE 64 HERE";
```

After that, you still need to assign pdfMake.fonts:

Open sans variations:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans:400,400i,600i,700

```
pdfMake.fonts = {
    // Make sure you define all 4 components - normal, bold, italics, bolditalics - (even if they all point to the same font file)
    "Open Sans": {  <======================= TRY WITH "OpenSans" too
        "normal": 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
        "bold": 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
        "italics": 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
        "bolditalics": 'OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'
    }
};
```

---

Another possible solution: (Not sure if it works)

```
let pdfMake = res[0];
let pdfFonts = require('./vfs_fonts');

pdfMake.addVirtualFileSystem(pdfFonts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the whitespace in `Open Sans`. Try to change it into `OpenSans`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same pdfmake library used by amcharts but you need to generate font as mentioned in the answer above by using gulp after npm install, there was promise issue so I replaced the syntax for just a quick workaround, so you have to go to the pdfmake folder located in the node_modules of you project root and run npm install after which you create fonts folder in the examples directory
-> examples/fonts and copy your ttf fonts there then run gulp file which will give you vfs_fonts.js file.

You need to edit this file and change

this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; pdfMake.vfs = {}

to

export const pdfMake={ vfs : {  }}; as in this screenshot:
 [image]

and end the key appropriately like this :

[image] instead of this `};`

after that you can check my full working code with montserrat font here which i made by using the amchart custom content demo below:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
import am4themes_dataviz from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/dataviz";

import * as pdfFontsVfs from "../../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Themes
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dataviz);

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {
  private chart: am4charts.XYChart;
  private chart2: am4charts.XYChart;
  private chart3: am4charts.XYChart;
  private chart4: am4charts.PieChart;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

    /**
     * Chart 1
     */

    // Create chart instance
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    // Add data
    chart.data = [{
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
      "value": 450,
      "value2": 362,
      "value3": 699
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
      "value": 269,
      "value2": 450,
      "value3": 841
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
      "value": 700,
      "value2": 358,
      "value3": 699
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
      "value": 490,
      "value2": 367,
      "value3": 500
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
      "value": 500,
      "value2": 485,
      "value3": 369
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 6),
      "value": 550,
      "value2": 354,
      "value3": 250
    }, {
      "date": new Date(2018, 0, 7),
      "value": 420,
      "value2": 350,
      "value3": 600
    }];

    // Create axes
    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;



    this.createSeries("value", "Series #1",chart);
    this.createSeries("value2", "Series #2",chart);
    this.createSeries("value3", "Series #3",chart);
    this.chart = chart;

    /**
     * Chart 2
     */

    // Create chart instance
    var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart2.paddingBottom = 25;

    // Add data
    chart2.data = [{
      "country": "USA",
      "visits": 3025
    }, {
      "country": "China",
      "visits": 1882
    }, {
      "country": "Japan",
      "visits": 1809
    }, {
      "country": "Germany",
      "visits": 1322
    }, {
      "country": "UK",
      "visits": 1122
    }, {
      "country": "France",
      "visits": 1114
    }, {
      "country": "India",
      "visits": 984
    }];

    // Create axes
    var categoryAxis2 = chart2.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "country";
    categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis2.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
    categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

    var valueAxis = chart2.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

    // Create series
    var series = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
    series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
    series.columns.template.strokeWidth = 0;

    series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 10;
    series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 10;

    // on hover, make corner radiuses bigger
    var hoverState = series.columns.template.column.states.create("hover");
    hoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 0;
    hoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopRight = 0;
    hoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;

    series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target)=>{
      return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
    });
    this.chart2 = chart2;
    /**
     * Chart 3
     */

    // Create chart instance
    var chart3 = am4core.create("chartdiv3", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart3.paddingBottom = 25;

    // Add percent sign to all numbers
    chart3.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.3'%'";

    // Add data
    chart3.data = [{
        "country": "USA",
        "year2004": 3.5,
        "year2005": 4.2
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "year2004": 1.7,
        "year2005": 3.1
    }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "year2004": 2.8,
        "year2005": 2.9
    }, {
        "country": "Japan",
        "year2004": 2.6,
        "year2005": 2.3
    }, {
        "country": "France",
        "year2004": 1.4,
        "year2005": 2.1
    }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "year2004": 2.6,
        "year2005": 4.9
    }];

    // Create axes
    var categoryAxis3 = chart3.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis3.dataFields.category = "country";
    categoryAxis3.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis3.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
    categoryAxis3.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

    var valueAxis3 = chart3.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis3.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

    // Create series
    var series3 = chart3.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series3.dataFields.valueY = "year2004";
    series3.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
    series3.clustered = false;

    series3.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 10;
    series3.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 10;

    var series2 = chart3.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series2.dataFields.valueY = "year2005";
    series2.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
    series2.clustered = false;
    series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(50);

    series2.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 6;
    series2.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 6;
    this.chart3 = chart3;
    /**
     * Chart 4
     */

    // Create chart
    var chart4 = am4core.create("chartdiv4", am4charts.PieChart);
    chart4.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    chart4.data = [
      {
        country: "Lithuania",
        value: 260
      },
      {
        country: "Czech Republic",
        value: 230
      },
      {
        country: "Ireland",
        value: 200
      },
      {
        country: "Germany",
        value: 165
      },
      {
        country: "Australia",
        value: 139
      },
      {
        country: "Austria",
        value: 128
      }
    ];

    var series4 = chart4.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
    series4.dataFields.value = "value";
    series4.dataFields.radiusValue = "value";
    series4.dataFields.category = "country";
    series4.slices.template.cornerRadius = 6;
    series4.colors.step = 3;
    series4.radius = am4core.percent(100);
    series4.labels.template.disabled = true;
    series4.ticks.template.disabled = true;
    this.chart4 = chart4;
    });
  }


  /**
   * Function that exports PDF
   */

  async savePDF() {

      var res = [];
      var fonts =  {
        "Montserrat": {
         normal: "Montserrat-Regular.ttf",
         bold: "Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
         italics: "Montserrat-Italic.ttf",
         bolditalics: "Montserrat-BoldItalic.ttf"
       }
     };
      var PdfMake = await this.chart.exporting.pdfmake;





      PdfMake.vfs = pdfFontsVfs.pdfMake.vfs;
      PdfMake.addVirtualFileSystem = pdfFontsVfs;
      PdfMake.fonts = fonts;

      res[1] = await this.chart.exporting.getImage("png");
      res[2] = await this.chart2.exporting.getImage("png");
      res[3] = await this.chart3.exporting.getImage("png");
      res[4] = await this.chart4.exporting.getImage("png");

      // pdfmake is ready

      // Create document template
      var doc = {
        pageSize: "A4",
        pageOrientation: "portrait",
        pageMargins: [30, 30, 30, 30],
        content: [],
        defaultStyle:{
          font: "Montserrat"
        }
      };

      doc.content.push({
        text: "In accumsan velit in orci tempor",
        fontSize: 20,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem quam, sodales ac volutpat sed, vestibulum id quam. Sed quis arcu non elit fringilla mattis. Sed auctor mi sed efficitur vehicula. Sed bibendum odio urna, quis lobortis dui luctus ac. Duis eu lacus sodales arcu tincidunt ultrices viverra a risus. Vivamus justo massa, malesuada quis pellentesque ut, placerat in massa. Nunc bibendum diam justo, in consequat ipsum fringilla ac. Praesent porta nibh ac arcu viverra, at scelerisque neque venenatis. Donec aliquam lorem non ultrices ultrices. Aliquam efficitur eros quis tortor condimentum, id pellentesque metus iaculis. Aenean at consequat neque, a posuere lectus. In eu libero magna. Pellentesque molestie tellus nec nisi molestie, eu dignissim lacus tristique. Sed tellus nulla, suscipit a velit non, mattis dictum metus. Curabitur mi mi, convallis nec libero quis, venenatis vestibulum ante.",
        fontSize: 15,
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        text: "Aliquam lacinia justo",
        fontSize: 20,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        image: res[1],
        width: 530
      });

      doc.content.push({
        text: "Phasellus suscipit in diam a interdum",
        fontSize: 20,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        table: {
          headerRows: 1,
          widths: [ "*", "*", "*", "*" ],
          body: [
            [
              { text: "USA", bold: true },
              { text: "Japan", bold: true },
              { text: "France", bold: true },
              { text: "Mexico", bold: true }
            ],
            [ "2500", "2500", "2200", "1200" ],
            [ "800", "1200", "990", "708" ],
            [ "2100", "2150", "900", "1260" ],
          ]
        }
      });

      doc.content.push({
        text: "Duis sed efficitur mauris",
        fontSize: 20,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        columns: [{
          image: res[2],
          width: 250
        }, {
          image: res[3],
          width: 250
        }],
        columnGap: 30
      });

      doc.content.push({
        text: "Aliquam semper lacinia",
        fontSize: 20,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 15]
      });

      doc.content.push({
        columns: [{
          image: res[4],
          width: 150
        }, {
          stack: [{
            text: "Maecenas congue leo vel tortor faucibus, non semper odio viverra. In ac libero rutrum libero elementum blandit vel in orci. Donec sit amet nisl ac eros mollis molestie. Curabitur ut urna vitae turpis bibendum malesuada sit amet imperdiet orci. Etiam pulvinar quam at lorem pellentesque congue. Integer sed odio enim. Maecenas eu nulla justo. Sed quis enim in est sodales facilisis non sed erat. Aenean vel ornare urna. Praesent viverra volutpat ex a aliquet.",
            fontSize: 15,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 15]
          }, {
       text: "Fusce sed quam pharetra, ornare ligula id, maximus risus. Integer dignissim risus in placerat mattis. Fusce malesuada dui ut lectus ultricies, et sollicitudin nisl placerat. In dignissim elit in pretium lobortis. Fusce ornare enim at metus laoreet, ut convallis elit lacinia. Maecenas pharetra aliquet mi. Nulla orci nunc, egestas id nisi ut, volutpat sollicitudin mi.",
        fontSize: 15,
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 15]
      }],
      width: "*"
    }],
    columnGap: 30
  });

    await  PdfMake.createPdf(doc,null, fonts,pdfFontsVfs.pdfMake.vfs).download("report.pdf");


  }

  // Create series
  createSeries(field, name, chart) {
    console.log(chart);
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = field;
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.name = name;
    series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
    series.strokeWidth = 3;

    var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
    bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 3;
    bullet.circle.radius = 7;
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.dispose();
        ...dispose other charts
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and webpack config is:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [ /node_modules/, /pdfmake.js$/ ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html|css)$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
    ],

}
```

and html is:

```
    <div class="main">

  <input type="button" value="Save as PDF" (click)="savePDF()" />

<h1>In accumsan velit in orci tempor</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem quam, sodales ac volutpat sed, vestibulum id quam. Sed quis arcu non elit fringilla mattis. Sed auctor mi sed efficitur vehicula. Sed bibendum odio urna, quis lobortis dui luctus ac. Duis eu lacus sodales arcu tincidunt ultrices viverra a risus. Vivamus justo massa, malesuada quis pellentesque ut, placerat in massa. Nunc bibendum diam justo, in consequat ipsum fringilla ac. Praesent porta nibh ac arcu viverra, at scelerisque neque venenatis. Donec aliquam lorem non ultrices ultrices. Aliquam efficitur eros quis tortor condimentum, id pellentesque metus iaculis. Aenean at consequat neque, a posuere lectus. In eu libero magna. Pellentesque molestie tellus nec nisi molestie, eu dignissim lacus tristique. Sed tellus nulla, suscipit a velit non, mattis dictum metus. Curabitur mi mi, convallis nec libero quis, venenatis vestibulum ante.</p>
<h2>Aliquam lacinia justo</h2>
<div id="chartdiv" class="chart"></div>

<h2>Phasellus suscipit in diam a interdum</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>USA</th>
    <th>Japan</th>
    <th>France</th>
    <th>Mexico</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2500</td>
    <td>1900</td>
    <td>2200</td>
    <td>1200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>1200</td>
    <td>990</td>
    <td>708</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2100</td>
    <td>2150</td>
    <td>900</td>
    <td>1260</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Duis sed efficitur mauris</h2>
<div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="chartdiv2" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div id="chartdiv3" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<h2>Aliquam semper lacinia</h2>
<div id="chartdiv4" class="chart"></div>
<p>Maecenas congue leo vel tortor faucibus, non semper odio viverra. In ac libero rutrum libero elementum blandit vel in orci. Donec sit amet nisl ac eros mollis molestie. Curabitur ut urna vitae turpis bibendum malesuada sit amet imperdiet orci. Etiam pulvinar quam at lorem pellentesque congue. Integer sed odio enim. Maecenas eu nulla justo. Sed quis enim in est sodales facilisis non sed erat. Aenean vel ornare urna. Praesent viverra volutpat ex a aliquet.</p>

<p>Fusce sed quam pharetra, ornare ligula id, maximus risus. Integer dignissim risus in placerat mattis. Fusce malesuada dui ut lectus ultricies, et sollicitudin nisl placerat. In dignissim elit in pretium lobortis. Fusce ornare enim at metus laoreet, ut convallis elit lacinia. Maecenas pharetra aliquet mi. Nulla orci nunc, egestas id nisi ut, volutpat sollicitudin mi.</p>

</div>
```

and package.json is :

```
    {
    "name": "angular-7-tutorial",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.9.1",
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.13",
        "@angular/router": "^7.2.13",
        "core-js": "^3.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^11.13.5",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
        "typescript": "^3.4.4",
        "webpack": "^4.30.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
    }
}
```

and folder structure:
[image]

The thing I understood is syntax conflict and promise unresolved failure preventing the charts pdf not loading the custom fonts. If you see the default amcharts vs_fonts file , you will see export default syntax which might caused the issue. Secondly check your font files if they are not corrupt.
Hope this will help you. Thanks.